# [OpenGL|C#]vhost32.exe has stopped working when glTexImage2D

Tags: c#, winapi, opengl, loading

My program crashed when I try to load a CubeMap.

```
    public static int LoadCubemap(string name, int size)
    {
        string folder = @"Resources\Textures\" + name + @"\";
        int returnInt = GL.GenTexture();
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, returnInt);

        //bytesPerPixel * width * (height \ 6) * faceIndex
        updloadTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapPositiveX, Image.FromFile(folder + "xpos.png"), size);
        updloadTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapNegativeX, Image.FromFile(folder + "xneg.png"), size);
        updloadTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapPositiveY, Image.FromFile(folder + "ypos.png"), size);
        updloadTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapNegativeY, Image.FromFile(folder + "yneg.png"), size);
        updloadTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapPositiveZ, Image.FromFile(folder + "zpos.png"), size);
        updloadTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapNegativeZ, Image.FromFile(folder + "zneg.png"), size);

        int nearest = (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest;
        GL.TexParameterI(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, ref nearest);
        GL.TexParameterI(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, ref nearest);

        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, 0);

        return returnInt;
    }

    private static void updloadTexture(TextureTarget target, Image texture, int size)
    {
        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapNegativeZ, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgb, size, size, 0, PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedByte, imageToByteArray(texture));
    }

    public static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image image)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

It crashes the 3rd or 4th time when GL.TexImage2D is called. I can't find why it does that. I use the .NET Image class and a converter I found on some other thread on this forum to convert a PNG to a `byte[]`.

Comment: So you seem to have some error in some code that uses some library taken from somewhere. Does that read like a helpful problem statement? If it doesn't, please [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41371737/edit) your question.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, the library I used was .NET and that is stated in the question. The imageToByteArray was in another Thread but you can see the whole Code - I can't see what you mean.

Comment: *"I use [...] a converter I found on some other thread on this forum"* - Leaving aside, that Stack Overflow is not a forum (it's a Q&A site), this is devoid of any useful information. You are also keeping the precise exception (and call stack) private, as well as the line of code that triggers it. Please see [ask].

Comment: Okay, that information is indeed irrelevant, but I didn't provide a call stack and exception because I dont have any information about that. The Program just closes with a window popping Up "vhost32.exe stopped workinh" without any indication why. And also I stated where it crashs - "It crashs the 3rd or 4rh time when GL.TexImage2D is called"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any details on the crash, so I can only speculate on why it's failing.

Perhaps the converter is running out of memory?

What I typically do instead of converting from Image to byte[] would be to use bitmaps and lockbits...

For example,

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap("path\\to\\file.png"))
{
    var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I cant provide any details on the crash, the little window when it says it stops working just opens at that Point... I will definetely try your idea next morning, I'm going to sleep now It's 2am where I live and I didn't expect an answer so fast ^^